# How to Align Horizontally sap.m.FlexBox Items of Different Height in SAPUI5?

Tags: sapui5

using `sap.m.FlexBox` inside of a `sap.m.Column` inside of a `sap.m.Table`. flex box's alignContent is set to Center. items of the flex box are e.g. a `sap.m.Input` and a `sap.m.Text`. the input control is heigher than the text. input gets aligned correctly to the center. text gets aligned to the top at the same level of the height of the input controller. is there any way without CSS to get the text aligned to the center of the column as well? i.e. not the the top of the input controller.

[image]

Comment: did you try using "vAlign" property in https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.m.ColumnListItem.html#getVAlign (in pair with "center" alignment of flex box)?

Comment: yep. unfortunately doesn't change anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[alignItems](https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.m.FlexBox.html#getAlignItems) property should do the job.

[image]

Comment: works. but why is there an alignContent, when there is an alignItems. don't see different use cases.

Comment: me either, but 'alignItems' is about the X coord alignment, and 'justifyContent' about the Y coord. Have never user the 'alignContent' :)

Answer (score 1):

work around is to use a sap.m.ObjectIdentifier instead of sap.m.Text.